# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.markers')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im constantly facing an error: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.markers'), which is weird, i dont know why i keep getting that.

This is my code below:

```
function ExploreScreen() {

  const handleUserLocation = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
      const newMapState = {
        markers,
        categories: [
          {
            name: "Nearby Events",
            icon: (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                style={styles.chipsIcon}
                name="near-me"
                size={18}
              />
            ),
          },
        ],
        region: {
          latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
          longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.04864195044303443,
          longitudeDelta: 0.040142817690068,
        },
      };
      alert(JSON.stringify(pos));
    });
  };

  const [state, setState] = React.useState(handleUserLocation);

  let mapIndex = 0;
  ...
```

Render function: (this is just a shorter version of the code, I had to delete alot show I can post here)

```
return (
    <>
      <Screen style={styles.screen}>
        <MapView
          ref={_map}
          initialRegion={region}
          style={styles.container}
        >
                      
          //some code go here
        </MapView>
```

Comment: `const [state, setState] = React.useState(handleUserLocation);` makes `state` point to a function; a function doesn't have a `.markers` property. Did you mean to call it instead, and return `newMapState` from the function?

Comment: Oh wow. Interesting, just learnt this today. What do you advice please.

Comment: Okay. I put newMapState in handleUserLocation because i wanted to be about to use it with somethings attached to newMapState i.e. Categories and markers... But i need to be able return newMapState as well  @ChrisG ... when i use `const [state, setState] = React.useState(newMapState);` it says cant find variable: newMapState

Comment: You can't return it from a callback. but you don't need to. Here's a minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-surf-x2dwc?file=/src/App.js (also: you're using hooks, and as a beginner you should definitely use classes instead)

Comment: @ChrisG - there's nothing wrong with using a function to supply the initial state. Your advice about using classes is off base as well.

Comment: @Adam where did I say there's something wrong with that? But you have to actually do it for it to work. Regarding classes vs. hooks: let's agree to vehemently disagree.

Comment: @ChrisG - in your firt comment where you said a function doesn't have a `markers` property. React accepts a function to initialize state as per [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state). You don't have to call it.

Comment: @Adam I didn't realize that, good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function to `useState` as per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state). Please note, however, you **CANNOT** use an async function - it must immediately return the state. As the docs say, it's used when computing the initial state is deemed expensive and you don't want to have to unnecessarily do it every time the component is rendered.

The problem is you need to return the initial state from that function. You are not doing that - you are returning `undefined` from that function and doing something in a callback. Rewrite the whole thing.

In words:

1. Keep the `region` as separate state.
2. Create your initial state for markers/categories (arguably, these are separate pieces of state that don't change together, however).
3. On mount, request the position and set the region state variable.
4. All effects after that should have region and/or state.markers as a dependency.

In code:

```js
function ExploreScreen() {

  const [region,setRegion] = useState(undefined);
  const [state,setState] = useState({
   markers:[],
   categories:{
            name: "Nearby Events",
            icon: (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                style={styles.chipsIcon}
                name="near-me"
                size={18}
              />
            ),
   }
  });

  useEffect(() {
    // on mount fetch the position and set the state
    navigator.geolocation.getPosition(pos => {
      setRegion(...whatever you want);
    });
  },[]);

  // after this, your effects should have a dependency of region AND/OR state.markers

}
```

Comment: One little bit please. I just notice it first goes to the undefined location before not displaying anything. Sometimes it goes to the correct lat&lng, What do you advice please

Comment: @NelsonKehinde one idea is to just not render the map until region is defined, you can just render a loader, or something blank instead while requesting the users location

Comment: Please @Adam I know im beginning to push it. But please can you give me a headstart, i prefer add a loader. Please

Comment: @NelsonKehinde update your question to show the rest of your render function.

Comment: @NelsonKehinde after all your hooks, if region is undefined, return a loader component. otherwise, return your map

Comment: Okay. I understand. Thank you @Adam, you are a genius. Wish i know these things as much as you do.